# Access input variable of lambda expression outside it's scope for Mocking Purpose in MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, lambda

I am using Moq for mocking a repository and want to use the parameter that was passed to the method of the mock object and return that parameter.
Following is the example of what I want to do.

```
ItemRepo.Setup(ir => ir.Find(It.Is<Item>(item => Items.Any(i => i.Id.Equals(item.Id)))))
                .Returns(item);
```

OR

```
ItemRepo.Setup(ir => ir.Find(It.Is<Item>(item => Items.Any(i => i.Id.Equals(item.Id)))))
                .Returns(item.Id);
```

Here ItemRepo is the mock of ITemsRepository and Items is list that I am using to simulate insertion and deletion into the database.
I am unable to access item variable that is the variable that will be passed to the find method of the mock object when this method will be called.
I just want to return item that satisfied the given condition from this method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a [callback](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks)?

Comment: No I just want to return whatevere was passes if it passess that constraint i.e if the item that was passed exists in Items List then it should just return the item.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value from a function that when you're not testing just returns the value.  e.g. `item => GetItem(Items.Any(i => i.Id.Equals(item.Id)))` You could also put the Items.Any(i => i...) into the GetItem function and just pass Items to that function.

```
private void Stuff()
{
ItemRepo.Setup(ir => FindItem(ir.Find(It.Is<Item>(item => Items.Any(i => i.Id.Equals(item.Id))))))
                .Returns(item)
}

private object FindItem(object p)
        {
            return p;
        }
```

Comment: Please eleborate

Comment: It's not working. How are you able to access item in .Returns(item) phrase, it gives error that it does not exist in current context.

Comment: If you can post a working example that doesn't need other code I'll modify it and post it back.  By which I mean a toy application that is separate from your main codebase and doesn't use any of the code in that codebase